# Display object when in IE or JavaScript is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display an HTML object (**#footer**) when the user is using Internet Explorer 8 or below or they have JavaScript disabled (or both).

How can I do this?

I hope you can understand my question and what I am trying to describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the footer's `display` CSS property set to `block` (or whatever you need it as) by default and use Javascript to hide it. If Javascript is disabled it won't be hidden. If Javascript is enabled, it would be hidden.

```
$("#footer").hide();
```

This line would hide it successfully (if Javascript is enabled, that is).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the conditional comments

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<![endif]-->
```

and or the `noscript` tag

```
<noscript>
</noscript>
```

Comment: use javascript to hide the stuff inside <noscript>

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ua = $.browser;

    if (!ua.msie || (ua.msie && parseInt(ua.version) > 8)) {
        $('#footer').hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hUN4k/

Basically, show on page load, use jQuery to detect if it's not `IE 8` or less.